# UICollectionViewCell hides when still in visible rectangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mobile

I have a **UICollectionView** with a number of cells. When i scroll, a cell that is bottom left hides before it leaves the screen. This replicates 100% and it's always the same cell. In landscape mode the cell index is different, but it also has a pattern.

In portrait it's the 9th cell and then the 19th cell.
In landscape mode is the 7th and 15th cell.

I think it would go further but i only got 19 objects in array right now.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxYh7.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf9ZB.png).

If i switch between these to content offsets with pan gesture it toogles the visibility of the cell.

Comment: That sounds like a bug... Are you using the iOS 8 beta?

Comment: No, i'm experiencing this problem on iOS 7.1. I have checked the frame of the cell and the Y property of the frame it's the same as for the cell on the right, but only the cell on the left dissapears.